# Геолокация, сервис, уведомления

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Добрый день. Пытаюсь сделать своё первое системное приложение под Андроид, связанное с геолокацией и локальными уведомлениями.
Я себе представляю это так: есть основное активити `MainActivity`, при старте оно запускает сервис, который при смене координат отсылает их на сервер, а в ответ получает какое-то сообщение, которое выводится как локальное уведомление.

Собственно, есть некоторые проблемы.

1. Если закрыть само приложение (через диспетчер задач), то сервис приостанавливает свою работу - при смене координат ничего не происходит.
   Что нужно сделать, чтобы сервис работал всё время? Или это принципиально невозможно?
2. При активации локального уведомления запускается активити `NotifyActivity` с подробной информацией. Там нажимаю `buttonDelete`, активити закрывается и происходит переход в `MainActivity`. Но если после этого переключиться на экран ОС (используя кнопку `Back`) и обратно, то вместо `MainActivity` опять отображается это самое `NotifyActivity`.
   Почему это происходит, как избежать?

MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "LocationTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate {
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(TestService)));
            button.Text = "Started";
        };
    }
}
```

Сервис геолокации

```
[Service]
public class TestService : Service, ILocationListener
{
    // запуск
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        locManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse;
        locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.Low;

        string locationProvider = locManager.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

        // Preferences.MinTime, например, 60 (секунд)
        // Preferences.MinDist, например, 100 (метров)
        locManager.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, Preferences.MinTime * 1000, Preferences.MinDist, this);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        // Отправка на сервер координат, обработка ответа, создание локального уведомления
        var msg = new ReceivedMessage(counter++, "Test Title", loc.ToString());
        ShowNotification(msg);
    }

    // отправка локальных уведомлений
    void ShowNotification(ReceivedMessage msg)
    {
        var myContainer = new Bundle();
        myContainer.PutLong("msg_id", Convert.ToInt64(msg.Id));
        myContainer.PutStringArray("msg_data", new [] { msg.Title, msg.Text });
        var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotifyActivity));
        resultIntent.PutExtras(myContainer);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotifyActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(Convert.ToInt32(msg.Id), PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(msg.Title)
            .SetContentText(msg.Text)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

        var nm = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        nm.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(msg.Id), builder.Build());
    }

}
```

локальные уведомления

```
[Activity(Label = "NotifyActivity")]            
public class NotifyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NotifyActivity);

        var msg_id = Intent.Extras.GetLong("msg_id");
        var msg_data = Intent.Extras.GetStringArray("msg_data");

        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textTitle).Text = msg_data[0];
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textDescription).Text = msg_data[1];

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonDelete).Click += delegate {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            Finish();
        };
    }
}
```

Пример проекта [тут](https://www.dropbox.com/s/burg0dsun82ivdj/LocationTest.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MainActivity добавьте этот код. Этот метод сделает то, что вам надо (но я не знаю как решить проблему с заголовком в recent activites).

```
public override bool OnKeyDown (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
        MoveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
}
```

Вообще работа с активностями в Андроид полна подводных камней. Так что советую просто вызывать MainActivity из сервиса, а потом уже из нее вызывать NotifyActivity, соотвественно потом вы просто вызываете MainActivity (с LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop).

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, что так и поступлю - буду вызывать из `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не специалист, но можете попробовать передать программу в фон.
Просто скрыть её, а не закрыть, как это происходит в большинстве приложений.
Или при кнопке назад с главного меню, спросите Выйти или Скрыть?
Я думаю так можно будет сделать.

А на счет второго вопроса, то сделайте его как объект. И при нажатии - уничтожайте его. Создайте такого рода себе конструктор-деструктор.

Сильно не пинайте.

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
[Activity(Label = "LocationTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

для MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "LocationTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
```

И замените `StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity))` на

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
StartActivity (intent);
Finish();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Артур. К сожалению, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, поправил ответ.

Comment: Заменил, всё равно то же самое поведение.

Comment: Я отвечал на второй вопрос. Мы про него говорили? На первый вопрос - попробуйте заменить [Service] на [Service (Process = ":remote")]

Comment: Да, я про второй вопрос

Comment: Тогда странно. Можете выложить весь проект куда-нибудь?

Comment: Я слегка изменил код, проверил, у меня работает.

Comment: Давайте убедимся в идентичности шагов. Я проверяю на Genymotion, API 19 (также проверял на других эмуляторах, и на планшете). И так, я запускаю приложение, появляется `MainActivity` (заголовок `LocationTest`) с кнопкой `Start service`. Нажимаю кнопку (GPS на устройстве включен), появляется значок уведомления вверху экрана. Открываю список уведомлений, нажимаю на уведомление. Появляется `NotifyActivity`, с кнопкой `Close`. Нажимаю `Close`, открывается `MainActivity`. Теперь нужно нажать кнопку `Back` (не `Home` - с ней всё работает нормально), произойдёт переключение на экран ОС

Comment: Затем нажимаю на кнопку диспетчера задач и там видно приложение с именем `NotifyActivity` (а не `LocationTest`), хотя превью отображает именно его. Нажимаю на превью - открывается `NotifyActivity` с кнопкой `Close`.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, про эту проблему совсем забыл. Я ответил отдельно как ее обойти, но лучшим решением будет вызывать MainActivity (или вообще какую-нибудь ProxyActivity) из сервиса.